# Retrieve bash function call execution time

Tags: bash, time

I am having some difficulties in getting the execution time of a bash script. Here's what I've tried:

```
/usr/bin/time -f'time: %e' func "arg"
```

but it doesn't work because `func` is a function, not a command.

I've tried various other approaches (`time` vs `/usr/bin/time`, `-p` param, subshells, no params) but no luck. How can I achieve this?

Comment: why don't you write a script that calls the function and time the script?

Comment: I need to benchmark an existing code and I don't want to overcomplicate things by modifying the code.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
function f() {
  sleep 1
  echo  BAM
}
TIMEFORMAT='%3R'
( time f "arg" ) 2> output
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. But how can I redirect `time`'s output to a file while preserving `func`'s output to stdout?

Comment: It doesn't put `time`'s output to the given file. The file remains empty.